# Add script to DOM that user inserts in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, script-tag

what i am trying to do is to get the value from a textbox and load it into a container like so:

```
var script = $('#txtbox').val();
$('.container').html(script);
```

i also tried creating the script again with javascript by finding the values of the one the user inserted and creating a new one and appending it into the container as so:

```
var tempdiv = $("<div></div>").html($('#txtbox').val());
$(tempdiv).find('script').each(function(index,$element){
     var script = document.createElement("script");
    $.each($element.attributes, function(){
        if (this.specified){
            script.setAttribute(this.name, this.value);
        }
    });
    script.innerHTML = $($element).html();
    $('.container').append(script); 
});
```

but still doesn't work, i get:

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script

Any suggestions? maybe try loading the script in iframe, refresh the DOM somehow or what?

Answer (score 0):

I solved that by using an iframe. In javascript i just created a form and a hidden input field which are submitted to the page that the iframe loads.

Check [JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit) for more details.